# Error in copying range using inputboxes from one sheet to anoyher

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to copy defined range through input-box to defined range through another input-box on other sheet.
I am getting error Run-time error "'1004'  Application define or object defined error". on line

```
          rngCopyFrom.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("rngCopyTo")
```

My level is beginner. Please guide me in what way to change it to serve the desired objective.

```
 Sub Sample()
  Dim rngCopyFrom As Range
  Dim rngCopyTo As Range
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rngCopyFrom = Application.InputBox("Enter the range from which you  ant to copy", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next
     Set rngCopyTo = Application.InputBox("Enter the range from     which   you       want to copy", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngCopyFrom Is Nothing Then
    '~~> Copy the range to Shhet2
    rngCopyFrom.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("rngCopyTo")
End If
End Sub
```

This program works If I define the fixed range as shown in line below.

```
           rngCopyFrom.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D14")
```

Comment: At a first glance I can see a problem with this: `Range("rngCopyTo")`. Do you really mean the string value `"rngCopyTo"`?

Comment: @Hauns TM I want to use the range specified by the second input box but I do not have any clue as how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with 2 input boxes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyRangeFromInputBoxes()

    Dim copyFrom As Range, copyTo As Range

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next            'if input is cancelled

    Set copyFrom = Application.InputBox("Select source range", Type:=8)

    If Not copyFrom Is Nothing Then 'if not cancelled

        Set copyTo = Application.InputBox("Select destination range", Type:=8)

        If Not copyTo Is Nothing Then copyFrom.Copy copyTo

    End If

End Sub
```

---

The code will copy from any sheet and paste on any other sheet:

[image]

Comment: Your suggested program works fine . Thanks a Lot. However it is pasting destination range on the same sheet, while I desire to post on another sheet say sheet2. Later I shall be taking this concept further to paste on another workbook sheet. Pl. look into if you can help further in this matter.

Comment: Not sure why for you it doesn't copy to another sheet but I just tested copying from Sheet1 to Sheet2 (see the image in my edited answer)

Comment: It works fine. I was making some mistake in properly inputting destination range. Thanks a lot.